# Parse http response in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing

I am making the following request:

```
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  session = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  headers = {}
  res = session.start do |http|
    http.get(request_url, headers)
  end
```

Response looks like this:

```
<string xmlns="http://xxx">
    some string
</string>
```

Is there some fast solution to parse the above response and get that `some string`. I can get it using a regexp but I would like use something which exists in Ruby.

Comment: Use.. `Nokogiri` to parse `res`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use any XML parser. For example, nokogiri:

```
require 'nokogiri'
n = Nokogiri::HTML::parse response
parsed_string = n.xpath('//string').text
```

Answer (score 1):

As Arup Rakshit commented, use [`nokogiri`](http://nokogiri.org/) to parse the xml:

```
require 'nokogiri'

res = <<EOS
<string xmlns="http://xxx">
    some string
</string>
EOS

root = Nokogiri.parse(res)
root.at_xpath('.//*[local-name()="string"]').text.strip  # Using xpath
# => "some string"
root.at_css('string').text.strip  # Using css selector
# => "some string"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse that XML using REXML or SimpleXML, and get the string.

I prefer SimpleXML.

### Sample

```
data['Result'].each do |item|
   item.sort.each do |k, v|
      if ["Title", "Url"].include? k
         print "#{v[0]}" if k=="Title"
         print " => #{v[0]}\n" if k=="Url"
      end
   end
end
```

https://developer.yahoo.com/ruby/ruby-xml.html